# Complexity and Big-O notation in mathematics

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I have only rough idea about computational complexity and Big-O notation.

Is these idea of algorithm applicable in mathematics too, or only in computer science?

If applicable in mathematics too,

1. Why the complexity of an expression similar to $n(n-1)$ is $O(n^2)$, not something like $O(n^2)\land O(n)$? Is it because how machines work? I mean we calculate $13^2$ from our memory, and for $31^2$ we use rules of multiplication, but machines need to add $31$ to $0$ for $31$ consecutive times, and hence most of the computational time is spent there, is it the reason? Even if such reasons apply, we know that the complexity of an expression similar to $n+5$ is $O(n)$, not $1$. Hence $O(n)$ is not negligible. Perhaps an explanation of the complexity of $n^3+n^2+n$ would clear things up.
2. What is the complexity of $(41n)^2-1$? Why?
3. What is the complexity of $n!/(n-2)!$ By cancelling out $(n-2)!$, we can have $O(n^2)$. But if we do not cancel out, I found that the complexity of factorial is $O(n^n)$. (I suppose machines don't have the idea of cancelling out yet.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are used in mathematics as well as computer science.  We may need to specify a "limit point" when talking about them.  In addition to $f(n) = O(g(n))$ as $n \to \infty$, we also see rates given when approaching some finite value: $f(x) = O(g(x))$ as $x \to 3$.

1. All of the following are correct (as $n \to \infty$):
   $$
   n(n-1) = O(n^2)
   \\
   n(n-1) = O(n^2+n)
   \\
   n(n-1) = O(4n^2-3n+7)
   \\
   n(n-1) = O(n^2+n^{3/2}+n+n^{1/2})
   \\
   n(n-1) = O(932n^2-12n+\pi)
   \\
   $$
   Can you guess why the most often chosen version is the first one?

Proofs for these:
$$
\lim_n \frac{n(n-1)}{n^2} = 1 < +\infty,
\\
\lim_n \frac{n(n-1)}{n^2+n} = 1 < +\infty,
\\
\lim_n \frac{n(n-1)}{4n^2-3n+7} = \frac{1}{4} < +\infty,
\\
\lim_n \frac{n(n-1)}{n^2+n^{3/2}+n+n^{1/2}} = 1 < +\infty,
\\
\lim_n \frac{n(n-1)}{932n^2-12n+\pi} = \frac{1}{932} < +\infty,
$$

---

2. I would choose
   $$
   (41n)^2-1 = O(n^2)
   $$
   but all the ones above are also correct.  The proof for $O(n^2)$
   looks like this:
   As $n \to \infty$ we have
   $$
   \frac{(41n)^2-1}{n^2} = \frac{1681 n^2 - 1}{n^2} = 1681 + \frac{-1}{n^2}
    \to 1681
   $$
   Any finite limit (or even lim sup) will be OK.

---

3. It is true that
   $$
   \frac{n!}{(n-2)!} = O(n^2)
   \tag1$$
   since
   $$
   \limsup_n \frac{n!/(n-2)!}{n^2} = 1 < +\infty
   $$
   It is also true that
   $$
   \frac{n!}{(n-2)!} = O(n^n)
   \tag2$$
   since
   $$
   \limsup_n \frac{n!/(n-2)!}{n^n} = 0 < +\infty
   $$
   But of course $(1)$ tells us more information than $(2)$, so
   (1) is a "better" choice.

---

Sometimes this notion of "better choice" is specified by saying
$$
\frac{n!}{(n-2)!} = \Theta(n^2)
$$
which means:
$$
\text{both}\quad \frac{n!}{(n-2)!} = O(n^2), \quad\text{and}\quad
n^2 = O\left(\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}\right)
$$

Comment: To your question, no. I also don't understand why 3rd, 4th, and 5th complexities are also acceptable. (In your answer to my question no 1.) For my question no 2 in OP, i used $n-2$, you used $n-1$ for equation no 1. Such difference should change the complexity; please check. For the last part, please name the specific topic to study so that I can understand it better; I am not familiar with such notation.

Comment: You are right, it should be $n-2$.